# Использование Node serialport с UART и CAN

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial, uart, can

Есть 2 сущности: микроконтроллер (к примеру Atega2560) и Rasbery Pi 4 с Ubuntu Server 20.04 на борту. На Rasbery будет сервер на nodejs. Изначально планировалось, что он при помощь npm serialport будет принимать данные в виде буфера, парсить их делать с ними дальнейшие действия, после чего формировать некое задание, собирать его в строку и отправлять в обратно в порт. На стороне микроконтроллера данные будут собираться в строку и отправляться в порт, после чего будет приниматься и праситься ответ. Но все это было легко на простых тестах на Arduno. Как известно на  Arduino используется UART, но в реальном устройстве хотелось бы использовать протокол CAN, так как сам по себе он лучше подошел бы для выполнения конкретных задач.

Вопрос. Может ли npm serialport работать с портом если на той стороне мы используем не UART, а CAN контроллер? Если нет, то какие решения существуют в nodejs для работы с CAN?

Comment: вы можете использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-can

Comment: Для чего вам CAN? CAN это физически другой интерфейс в отличии от UART. Вы уже определитесь что хотите использовать.